# What happens if Ansible fails of a couple of Server

Tags: ansible

I have a lot of servers and I want to use Ansible to manage all of them. The problem is what will happen if a configuration with ansible fails on some servers? Does the ansible server will automatically push the modification? Also if a machine is shutdowned, will ansible execute the script when the server will be on?

Example :
 [servers]
  server1
  server2
  ....
  server1000

The servers 50,51,52 are shutdowned. Should I manually execute ansible for these servers when they will be online or Ansible does it automatically?

I hope you understand me

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Ansible does not automatically re-run playbooks for you.

However, you could setup your playbooks on a cron job. This way when the servers come back online, they will receive the Ansible run.

Another approach could be inverting the normal "push" behavior with `ansible-pull` http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull  This way the when the hosts come online, they run the Ansible stuff on their own.

Comment: Thank you Mike, that was what I'm searching. Regards